# Is $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ the cohomology group or the vector space of holomorphic differentials in a Riemann surface $X$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, riemann-surfaces

I am an undergraduate studying Riemann surfaces so I don't have a huge background in algebra. As far as I know, $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ is the cohomology group of $X$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{C}$. However, in some books I saw that people also call $H^1(X,\mathbb{C})$ the complex vector space of holomorphic differentials. I don't see the relationship between these objects.

Are they really the same object? If so, why?

Comment: I'm more familiar with the algebraic perspective, but since there is an equivalence between Riemann sufaces and complex algebraic curves, it should be possible to translate. I think this should follow from [Serre duality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serre_duality), which implies that $H^1(X, \mathscr{O}_X) \cong H^0(X, \Omega_X)^\vee$, where $\Omega_X$ is the sheaf of holomorphic differentials and the $\vee$ denotes the dual space. But it's exactly that extra dual that bothers me... At least this shows the two spaces have the same dimension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit** As peter a g points out below, Hodge theory tells us that $H^1(X,\Bbb{C})=H^{(1,0)}(X,\Bbb{C})\oplus H^{(0,1)}(X,\Bbb{C})$, where $H^{(1,0)}$ are the holomorphic 1-forms and $H^{(0,1)}$ are the antiholomorphic 1-forms. I've got to figure out where exactly I lost the antiholomorphic 1-forms below.

**Edit 2** Oh, I figured it out. I was being silly and starting with the assumption that my 1-form was a multiple of $dz$ to begin with. So the story is a bit more complicated than I originally described, but the general idea is correct.

**More or less fixed version:**

By [de Rham's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Rham_cohomology#De_Rham's_theorem), we can regard $H^1(X,\Bbb{C})$ as being the complexification of $\newcommand{\dR}{\text{dR}}H^1_{\dR}(X)$, which is the set of closed differential 1-forms with coefficients in $\Bbb{C}$ modulo the set of exact differential 1-forms with coefficients in $\Bbb{C}$.

Working locally, we may assume that we have $U\subseteq \Bbb{C}$. When is a differential $1$-form $P\,dx + Q\, dy$ closed? Well, it's precisely when $Q_x-P_y=0$, since
$$d(P\,dx+Q\, dy)=(Q_x-P_y)\,dx\wedge dy.$$

Now since we are doing complex analysis, it's nicer to use the basis $dz = dx+i\,dy$ and $d\bar{z}=dx-i\,dy$ for the basis for our differential forms.

We can therefore write any complex differential form locally as $f \,dz + g\, d\bar{z}$ (where $f,g$ are smooth functions to $\Bbb{C}$).

So let's now consider what happens when $g=0$, so we just have $f=u+iv$.

Let's apply the condition for a differential form to be closed to the differential form 
$$f\,dz=(u+iv)(dx+i\,dy)=(u+iv)\, dx +(-v+ui)\, dy.$$
This differential form is closed when $(-v+ui)_x = (u+iv)_y$, i.e., when $u_y=-v_x$ and $u_x = v_y$.

However these equations are precisely the [Cauchy-Riemann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%E2%80%93Riemann_equations), so a differential 1-form of the form $f\,dz$ on $X$ is closed if and only if it is holomorphic.

Now it would be nice if we could always decompose our forms into $f\,dz+g\,d\bar{z}$ such that the differential form is closed if and only if both pieces are closed. This is not always possible, but it is possible when $X$ is a compact [Kähler manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%A4hler_manifold). This is the content of the [Hodge theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory#Hodge_theory_for_complex_projective_varieties).

**I think I'll have to come back and check this last part, but it should be more or less correct**

Then the explanation for why $H^{(1,0)}(X)$ is the space of holomorphic $1$-forms when $X$ is a compact Kähler manifold is more or less the same as my prior explanation, since holomorphic $1$-forms are the $1$-forms locally of the form $f\, dz$, with $f$ holomorphic.

Then the exact forms are the forms $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z} \,dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \bar{z}}\, d\bar{z},$$
and when $\frac{\partial f}{partial \bar{z}}=0$, $f$ is holomorphic. However since $X$ is compact, global holomorphic functions are constants. Thus there are no nonzero exact holomorphic 1-forms.

**Note**

It's safe to write $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$ even though a priori we only know $f$ is $C^\infty$ because if $f=u+iv$, then 
$$df = f_x\,dx + f_y\,dy = f_x\,dx +(-if_y)i\,dy$$
$$= \frac{f_x-if_y}{2} \, dz + \frac{f_x+if_y}{2} \, d\bar{z}.$$
Then if we know $f_x+if_y=0$, then if $f=u+iv$, we get $u_x+iv_x = -iu_y + v_y$, which are once again the Cauchy-Riemann equations. Thus by the decomposition of closed forms, if an exact form $df$ ends up in $\Omega^{(1,0)}$, $f$ must have been holomorphic.

Comment: This works in the same way for $H^1(X,\mathbb{Z})$? Also, is it possible to see the relative cohomology in this way? Thanks for your answer, it already helped a lot!

Comment: Here, $H^1 = H^{(1,0)}+ H^{(0,1)}$ - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hodge_theory. For instance, $\dim H^1= 2g$, where $g= \dim H^{(1,0)}$. So this answer is not quite right... (but not unhelpful!)

Comment: @peterag That's a good point, hm, let me think about it.

Comment: @peterag Edited, I think this fixes the problem. Thanks for your comment. I was being very silly earlier.